# Error in tab Layout sub activity for android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I have created tab widget for my application. Each activity have an multiple sub activities. My main activity is

```
package com.example.travelmate;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TaxiActivity extends ActivityGroup 
{

Button taxi_meter_btn1,taxi_meter_btn2;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.taxi_layout);


    taxi_meter_btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.meter_bt1);
    taxi_meter_btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.meter_bt2);


    taxi_meter_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            Intent activity3Intent = new Intent(v1.getContext(),TaxiMeterActivityMain.class);
            replaceContentView1("activity3", activity3Intent);


        }
    });

    taxi_meter_btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v2)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            Intent activity4Intent = new Intent(v2.getContext(),TaxiMeterActivityMain.class);
            replaceContentView2("activity3", activity4Intent);


        }
    });





}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void replaceContentView1(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();
    this.setContentView(view);
}
public void replaceContentView2(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();
    this.setContentView(view);
}
}
```

My sub activity is

```
 public class TaxiMeterActivityMain extends ActivityGroup
 {

Button end_jour_btn;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.taxi_meter_layout);



    end_jour_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.end_jour_bt);



    end_jour_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Intent activity3Intent = new Intent(TaxiMeterActivityMain.this, TaxiActivity.class);
            replaceContentView("activity3", activity3Intent);
        }
    });


}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
            .getDecorView();
    this.setContentView(view);
}
 }
```

I want to call this sub activity for two different buttons for two times. When i click the first button I can back to main activity. But when click the second button for same activity it raises error like this http://pastie.org/8420928. How can i resolve this can anybody help me? Thank in advance.

Comment: why are you using deprecated stuff? you should update your code instead of using `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`.

Also don't send the views context, use the Application Context instead.

Why do you have 2 equal methods? (`replaceContentView1` and `replaceContentView2`) 

Also read this please http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP